# MVC 5 Complex View Model binding is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

```
public class CreateProjeModel
{
    public Proje Proje { get; set; }
    public List<GeometryModel> GeometryList { get; set; }
    public CreateProjeModel()
    {
        Proje = new Proje();
        GeometryList = new List<GeometryModel>();
    }
}

public class GeometryModel
{
    public List<PointModel> PointList { get; set; }

    public GeometryModel()
    {
        PointList = new List<PointModel>();
    }
}

public class PointModel
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public class Proje : EntityBase
{
    public int FirmaId { get; set; }
    public int IlId { get; set; }
    public int? IlceId { get; set; }
    public int PlanTurId { get; set; }
    public int EtudTurId { get; set; }
    public int EtudAmacId { get; set; }
    public int DilimId { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }

    public virtual Firma Firma { get; set; }
    public virtual IL Il { get; set; }
    public virtual ILCE Ilce { get; set; }
    public virtual PlanTur PlanTur { get; set; }
    public virtual EtudTur EtudTur { get; set; }
    public virtual EtudAmac EtudAmac { get; set; }
    public virtual Dilim Dilim { get; set; }

}
```

I have a complex model named CreateProjeModel. I'm using 'for' to loop collection properties and binding like below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GeometryList[i].PointList[j].X)
```

Action is like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateProjeModel proje)
{
    //ToDo
    return View(proje);
}
```

Posted data is below:

[image]

When it comes to action, GeometryList is empty and Proje's properties are not set to post values. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `CreateProjeModel` model has a property named `Proje`, but the parameter of your `Create()` method is also named `proje`. Your need to change the method signature to (say)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateProjeModel model)
```

where the parameter name is not the same as the nae of one of your properties

Comment: I never tought about it. Thanks. I was about starting to write my custom binder. Is there any documentation of default model binder?